# how we can create External UDF to execute N1QL?

Tags: javascript, couchbase, couchbase-sync-gateway

i had created External UDF to execute N1QL but when we execute function then get error

function that i created

```
function myFunction() {
     var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;
     query = N1qlQuery.fromString('select * from test.`101`.cust1  where Meta().id=\"101::13::CUST1::1::000a4aed-5b51-45e7-8294-ac4e320d2291\"');
     retrun bucket.query(query).toString()
  }
```

2nd way that i had tried

```
function myFunction() {
 var cluster = Cluster.connect(\"127.0.0.1\", \"Administrator\", \"password\");
 var bucket = cluster.bucket(\"test\");
 var scope =bucket.scope(\"101\");
 var collections  =scope.collection(\"cust1\");
 var N1qlQuery = couchbase.N1qlQuery;

 query = N1qlQuery.fromString('select * from test.`101`.cust1  where Meta().id=\"101::13::CUST1::1::000a4aed-5b51-45e7-8294-ac4e320d2291\"'); 
 retrun bucket.query(query).toString()
 }
```

"

error that i get

[image]

[image]

Comment: Is this eventing function vs UDF

Comment: this is simple External User Defined Function using javascript . this is not eventing function

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to say that at this moment in time javascript UDFs cannot execute N1QL statements, which explains why your UDFs fail.

Comment: I am using couchbase 7.0 beta, As per docs we can exeute query in inline user defined function.. And external user defined function only support javascript. Just I am trying to figure out can we execute query in external user defined function.? If yes then how? If no then why?  Is in couchbase 7.0 beta support query in external user defined function?